# Can't @apply Tailwind state variant classes using Eleventy and Sass

Tags: sass, tailwind-css, eleventy

#### Problem:

I’m using 11ty with Tailwind and Sass. Whenever I use a Tailwind state variant class in a .scss file (eg. `.class { @apply sm:flex }`) it negates the entire CSS rule, including all other classes declared with it.

**I'd love to be able to `@apply` Tailwind state variant classes (`sm:*`, `hover:*`, `group-hover:*` in .scss files.**

---

#### Background:

I started my project using 11ty with just Tailwind. I’d be able to write `@apply` Tailwind state variant classes like this without issue:

```
.class {
  @apply flex sm:flex-col;
}
```

This would define define `display: flex;` for wide screens and `flex-direction: column;` for small screens sizes (I flipped Tailwind’s mobile first approach, please don’t judge :) ).

Everything was working fine, but I wanted nesting and few other Sass features, so I installed [this Sass plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eleventy-plugin-sass). Afterward this, I’m still able to `@apply` Tailwind classes without a `:` in them like so:

```
.class {
  @apply flex p-6 m-6;
}
```

This ^^ outputs as expected. However when I add a class with a `:`, it negates the entire line.

```
.class {
  @apply flex p-6 m-6 hover:bg-white;
}
```

This line outputs nothing. Doesn’t produce a build error. Doesn’t compile anything for `.class`. All CSS declarations without a state variant class are successfully output, along with the rest of the site’s HTML/JS.

---

In many cases I can define things differently, like so:

```
.class {
  @apply flex p-6 m-6; 

  &:hover {
    @apply bg-white;
  }
}
```

This ^^ works just fine.

I can also use Tailwind classes directly in markup:

```
<div class=“flex p-6 m-6 hover:bg-white”></div>
```

While I can get really far with these two techniques, there are still a few places where it’d be really nice to `@apply` a state variant in a .scss file.

Maybe I configured the Sass plugin improperly? JS is not my strong suit. Here’s the relevant bits of my `eleventy.js` file:

```
const pluginTailwind = require('eleventy-plugin-tailwindcss');
const pluginSass = require("eleventy-plugin-sass");

module.exports = (config) => {
  config.addPlugin(pluginTailwind, {
    src: 'src/assets/css/*'
  });
  config.addPlugin(pluginSass, {
    outputDir: './'
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure Your `Scss` is loading after `tailwind`. you can also check which file is importing 1st at `index.js`.
Did you check by pesting these at the same scss file:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is how I'm currently doing it: Tailwind.css first followed by custom css.

Comment: Welcome, If you found my answer useful, you can accept it as the best answer or give it a plus. It will be so helpful for me.